# If A is a n*n matrix with only 1 eigenvalue a, how can we show that A is an upper triangular matrix with all diagonal entries as a.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying for a long time now but not reaching anywhere. Can you please give me a hint on how to appraoch this question?
Will be very grateful.

Comment: On what field are you working?

Comment: I am a student pursuing a degree in Mathematics

Comment: I understand, that does not answer the question. Are the coefficients of your matrix real ones? Complex ones?

Comment: I am so sorry. Yes they are real.

Comment: Sorry for the mismatch! Different meanings for *field*!

Answer (score 1):

As stated, and working with real matrices, the statement may be wrong. If that would be the case, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ would always split which may not be the case. For example if

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$a$ is the only real eigenvalue of $A$ though.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: When the user name fits...

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take
$$
A=\pmatrix{ a & 0 \\1 & a}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response :)